# recursive issue with getter ios objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter = getSolutionsCount, setter = setSolutionsCount:) NSInteger solutionsCount;
```

and implementation

```
- (NSInteger)getSolutionsCount {
    return self.solutionsCount;
}
```

and I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this method `- (NSInteger)getSolutionsCount`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dot syntax is basically a shortcut for calling the getter. You have infinite recursion in your getter method.

What you need to do is return the instance variable directly:

```
- (NSInteger)getSolutionsCount {
    //latest xcode makes variables with _property name automatically
    return _solutionsCount;

    //older versions of xcode or having written @synthesize solutionsCount
    //will necessitate
    //return solutionsCount;
}
```

Also just FYI objective-c convention is to have the getter method be defined as just the variable name. A getter which is the same as the property name is assumed if you don't write a getter in the property declaration

EDIT:
also i'm assuming this isnt the whole implementation for your getter because if it is let the compiler make it for you automatically, you don't need to write anything. (or by writing `@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName` in your implementation block with older versions of xCode)

Comment: +1 for noting the differences between properties generated by the old compiler and the new one

Answer (score 3):

The line `self.solutionsCount` is translated to `[self getSolutionCount]`. You are making a recursive call.

If you simply want to return the synthesized ivar then don't even implement this method. But if you do then simply call `return _solutionCount;`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `self.solutionsCount` is identical to `[self getSolutionsCount]`, so your getter is directly recursive. You probably want to access the underlying ivar directly, to do so use `self->_solutionsCount`. Or, if you prefer not to explicitly use `self`, simply `_solutionsCount`.

Comment: And to point out additional information, a call to `self->ivar` is identical to simply referencing the ivar.

Comment: Yes, I know. I prefer to use self to make it clear I'm referring to the ivar and not a local variable.

Comment: @Kevin Good point but the leading underscore is typically enough to differentiate ivars from other vars assuming that pattern is used. Of course in this case, there is no need for the entire 'getter' method anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here:

1. According to the naming convention getters should not start with get. To read the value you need to use `self.solutionsCount`. Hence, you do not need to specify the name of the getter method in the property declaration.
2. You do not need to specify the name of the setter for it will be automatically generated.

The property should look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger solutionsCount;
```

1. You do not need to write a custom getter implementation to make it work. Ask the compiler to synthesize the methods for you:

   @synthesize solutionsCount;

If you want to have a direct access to the instance variable, ask compiler to sythesize it for you:

```
@synthesize solutionsCount = _solutionsCount;
```

1. Read objective-c and naming convention docs first. They will help enormously.

Good luck!

Comment: you don't even need to @synthesize any more with the latest xCode

Comment: Cool! Even simpler :) I just wanted to download the new one this morning.

Comment: To be precise the compiler now does the equivalent of `@synthesize solutionsCount = _solutionsCount;` (including the _variable bit) so if you were doing it right all along and following the conventions you can probably delete most of your @synthesize declarations now